# Mutate multiple columns in a dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, stata

I have a data set that looks like this.

```
bankname    bankid   year    totass    cash    bond    loans
Bank A      1        1881    244789    7250    20218   29513
Bank B      2        1881    195755    10243   185151  2800
Bank C      3        1881    107736    13357   177612  NA
Bank D      4        1881    170600    35000   20000   5000
Bank E      5        1881    3200000   351266  314012  NA
```

and I want to compute some ratios based on bank balance sheets. and I want the dataset to look like this

```
bankname    bankid   year    totass    cash    bond    loans    CashtoAsset   BondtoAsset    LoanstoAsset
Bank A      1        1881    2447890   7250    202100  951300   0.002         0.082          0.388
Bank B      2        1881    195755    10243   185151  2800     0.052         0.945          0.014
Bank C      3        1881    107736    13357   177612  NA       0.123         1.648585431    NA
Bank D      4        1881    170600    35000   20000   5000     0.205         0.117          0.029
Bank E      5        1881    32000000  351266  314012  NA       0.0109        0.009          NA
```

Here is the code to replicate the data

```
bankname <- c("Bank A","Bank B","Bank C","Bank D","Bank E")
bankid <- c( 1, 2,  3,  4,  5)
year<- c( 1881, 1881,   1881,   1881,   1881)
totass  <- c(244789,    195755, 107736, 170600, 32000000)
cash<-c(7250,10243,13357,35000,351266)
bond<-c(20218,185151,177612,20000,314012)
loans<-c(29513,2800,NA,5000,NA)
bankdata<-data.frame(bankname, bankid,year,totass, cash, bond, loans)
```

First, I got rid of NAs in balance sheets.

```
cols <- c("totass", "cash", "bond", "loans")
bankdata[cols][is.na(bankdata[cols])] <- 0
```

Then I compute ratios

```
library(dplyr)
bankdata<-mutate(bankdata,CashtoAsset = cash/totass)
bankdata<-mutate(bankdata,BondtoAsset = bond/totass)
bankdata<-mutate(bankdata,loanstoAsset =loans/totass)
```

But, instead of computing all these ratios line by line, I want to create a look to do this all at once. In Stata, I would do

```
foreach x of varlist cash bond loans {
by bankid: gen `x'toAsset = `x'/ totass
}
```

How would I do this?

Comment: Meta-comments: When translating from one language to another, you need not be too literal. Loops in Stata often work better as array-based calculations in R. (Even the converse can be true: newcomers to Stata from other languages often try loops over observations, which are rarely needed.)

Comment: I simplify my variables here, but in my dataset, I have over 20 categories of assets, so having a loop is helpful.

Comment: I have nothing against loops; similarly the typical R user is surely happy with 20 columns....

Comment: @NickCox As always, Thank you for your help. I am learning a lot from you.

Comment: @akrun Thanks for letting me know. I will do that from now on.

Answer (score 50):

## Update (as of the 18th of March, 2019)

There has been a change. We have been using `funs()` in `.funs` (`funs(name = f(.)`). But this is changed (dplyr 0.8.0 above). Instead of `funs`, now we use `list` (`list(name = ~f(.))`). See the following new examples.

```
bankdata %>%
mutate_at(.funs = list(toAsset = ~./totass), .vars = vars(cash:loans))

bankdata %>%
mutate_at(.funs = list(toAsset = ~./totass), .vars = c("cash", "bond", "loans"))

bankdata %>%
mutate_at(.funs = list(toAsset = ~./totass), .vars = 5:7)
```

## Update (as of the 2nd of December, 2017)

Since I answered this question, I have realized that some SO users have been checking this answer. The dplyr package has changed since then. Therefore, I leave the following update. I hope this will help some R users to learn how to use `mutate_at()`.

`mutate_each()` is now deprecated. You want to use `mutate_at()`, instead. You can specify which columns you want to apply your function in `.vars`. One way is to use `vars()`. Another is to use a character vector containing column names, which you want to apply your custom function in `.fun`. The other is to specify columns with numbers (e.g., 5:7 in this case). Note that, if you use a column for `group_by()`, you need to change the numbers of column positions. Have a look of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47355085/mutate-at-evaluation-error-when-using-group-by).

```
bankdata %>%
mutate_at(.funs = funs(toAsset = ./totass), .vars = vars(cash:loans))

bankdata %>%
mutate_at(.funs = funs(toAsset = ./totass), .vars = c("cash", "bond", "loans"))

bankdata %>%
mutate_at(.funs = funs(toAsset = ./totass), .vars = 5:7)

#  bankname bankid year   totass   cash   bond loans cash_toAsset bond_toAsset loans_toAsset
#1   Bank A      1 1881   244789   7250  20218 29513   0.02961734  0.082593581    0.12056506
#2   Bank B      2 1881   195755  10243 185151  2800   0.05232561  0.945830247    0.01430359
#3   Bank C      3 1881   107736  13357 177612    NA   0.12397899  1.648585431            NA
#4   Bank D      4 1881   170600  35000  20000  5000   0.20515826  0.117233294    0.02930832
#5   Bank E      5 1881 32000000 351266 314012    NA   0.01097706  0.009812875            NA
```

I purposely gave `toAsset` to the custom function in `.fun` since this will help me to arrange new column names. Previously, I used `rename()`. But I think it is much easier to clean up column names with `gsub()` in the present approach. If the above result is saved as `out`, you want to run the following code in order to remove `_` in the column names.

```
names(out) <- gsub(names(out), pattern = "_", replacement = "")
```

## Original answer

I think you can save some typing in this way with dplyr. The downside is you overwrite cash, bond, and loans.

```
bankdata %>%
    group_by(bankname) %>%
    mutate_each(funs(whatever = ./totass), cash:loans)

#  bankname bankid year   totass       cash        bond      loans
#1   Bank A      1 1881   244789 0.02961734 0.082593581 0.12056506
#2   Bank B      2 1881   195755 0.05232561 0.945830247 0.01430359
#3   Bank C      3 1881   107736 0.12397899 1.648585431         NA
#4   Bank D      4 1881   170600 0.20515826 0.117233294 0.02930832
#5   Bank E      5 1881 32000000 0.01097706 0.009812875         NA
```

If you prefer your expected outcome, I think some typing is necessary. The renaming part seems to be something you gotta do.

```
bankdata %>%
    group_by(bankname) %>%
    summarise_each(funs(whatever = ./totass), cash:loans) %>%
    rename(cashtoAsset = cash, bondtoAsset = bond, loanstoAsset = loans) -> ana;
    ana %>%
    merge(bankdata,., by = "bankname")

#  bankname bankid year   totass   cash   bond loans cashtoAsset bondtoAsset loanstoAsset
#1   Bank A      1 1881   244789   7250  20218 29513  0.02961734 0.082593581   0.12056506
#2   Bank B      2 1881   195755  10243 185151  2800  0.05232561 0.945830247   0.01430359
#3   Bank C      3 1881   107736  13357 177612    NA  0.12397899 1.648585431           NA
#4   Bank D      4 1881   170600  35000  20000  5000  0.20515826 0.117233294   0.02930832
#5   Bank E      5 1881 32000000 351266 314012    NA  0.01097706 0.009812875           NA
```

Comment: Hi, I am trying all different options posted here. When I tried your codes, I got. `Error: object 'ana' not found. Would you explain to me what is going on? Thanks.

Comment: @HPark I am assigning an output to the object, ana in the piping process. If this approach does not work for you, you could do, `ana <- bankdata %>% group_by(bankname) %>% summarise_each(funs(whatever = ./totass), cash:loans) %>% rename(cashtoAsset = cash, bondtoAsset = bond, loanstoAsset = loans); ana %>% merge(bankdata,., by = "bank name")`

Comment: Reminder from 2022: all of the above have been deprecated; the state of the art would be `dplyr::mutate(dplyr::across(.cols = c(cash:loans), .fns=~.x/totass, .names="{.col}ToAsset"))`. Notable changes: there is no need to user `vars()` anymore, a simple `c()` will do; and there is no need to overwrite columns anymore.

Answer (score 4):

`Apply` and `cbind`

```
cbind(bankdata,apply(bankdata[,5:7],2, function(x) x/bankdata$totass))
names(bankdata)[8:10] <- paste0(names(bankdata)[5:7], 'toAssest’)

> bankdata
  bankname bankid year   totass   cash   bond loans cashtoAssest bondtoAssest loanstoAssest
1   Bank A      1 1881   244789   7250  20218 29513   0.02961734  0.082593581    0.12056506
2   Bank B      2 1881   195755  10243 185151  2800   0.05232561  0.945830247    0.01430359
3   Bank C      3 1881   107736  13357 177612    NA   0.12397899  1.648585431            NA
4   Bank D      4 1881   170600  35000  20000  5000   0.20515826  0.117233294    0.02930832
5   Bank E      5 1881 32000000 351266 314012    NA   0.01097706  0.009812875            NA
```

Comment: In the code cbind(bankdata,apply(bankdata[,5:7],2, function(x) x/bankdata$totass)), what does the 2 signify?

Comment: @Skurup,   "2" is the "margin" argument within the `apply` function. It means that the function will be applied to the columns vector. "1" instead would apply the function to rows. ( check `?apply`)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a `data.table` solution.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(bankdata)
bankdata[, paste0(names(bankdata)[5:7], "toAsset") := 
           lapply(.SD, function(x) x/totass), .SDcols=5:7]
bankdata
#    bankname bankid year   totass   cash   bond loans cashtoAsset bondtoAsset loanstoAsset
# 1:   Bank A      1 1881   244789   7250  20218 29513  0.02961734 0.082593581   0.12056506
# 2:   Bank B      2 1881   195755  10243 185151  2800  0.05232561 0.945830247   0.01430359
# 3:   Bank C      3 1881   107736  13357 177612     0  0.12397899 1.648585431   0.00000000
# 4:   Bank D      4 1881   170600  35000  20000  5000  0.20515826 0.117233294   0.02930832
# 5:   Bank E      5 1881 32000000 351266 314012     0  0.01097706 0.009812875   0.00000000
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the big downsides of `dplyr`: as far as I'm aware, there is no straightforward way to use it programmatically rather than interactively without some kind of "hack" like the deplorable `eval(parse(text=foo))` idiom.

The simplest approach is the same as in the Stata method, but string manipulation is a little more verbose in R than in Stata (or in any other scripting language, for that matter).

```
for (x in c("cash", "bond", "loans")) {
  bankdata[sprintf("%stoAsset", x)] <- bankdata[x] / bankdata$totass  # or, equivalently, bankdata["totass"] for a consistent "look"
  ## can also replace `sprintf("%stoAsset", x)` with `paste0(c(x, "toAsset"))` or even `paste(x, "toAsset", collapse="") depending on what makes more sense to you.
}
```

To make the whole thing more Stata-like, you can wrap the whole thing in `within` like so:

```
bankdata <- within(bankdata, for (x in c("cash", "bond", "loans")) {
  assign(x, get(x) / totass)
})
```

but this entails some hacking with the `get` and `assign` functions which aren't as safe to use in general, although in your case it's probably not a big deal. I wouldn't recommend trying similar tricks with `dplyr`, for instance, because `dplyr` abuses R's nonstandard evaluation features and it's probably more trouble than it's worth. For a faster and probably superior solution, check out the `data.table` package which (I think) would allow you to use the Stata-like looping syntax but with `dplyr`-like speed. Check out the package vignette on CRAN.

Also, are you really, really sure you want to reassign `NA` entries to 0?

Answer (score 0):

You might be making this a little harder than necessary.  Just try this and see if it yields what you need.

```
bankdata$CashtoAsset <- bankdata$cash / bankdata$totass
bankdata$BondtoAsset <- bankdata$bond / bankdata$totass
bankdata$loantoAsset <- bankdata$loans / bankdata$totass
bankdata
```

Yields this:

```
    bankname bankid year   totass   cash   bond   loans  CashtoAsset BondtoAsset loantoAsset
1   Bank A    1     1881     244789   7250  20218 29513  0.02961734  0.082593581 0.12056506
2   Bank B    2     1881     195755  10243 185151  2800  0.05232561  0.945830247 0.01430359
3   Bank C    3     1881     107736  13357 177612     0  0.12397899  1.648585431 0.00000
4   Bank D    4     1881     170600  35000  20000  5000  0.20515826  0.117233294 0.02930832
5   Bank E    5     1881   32000000 351266 314012     0  0.01097706  0.009812875 0.00000000
```

This should get you started in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
for(i in 5:7){
     bankdata[,(i+3)] = bankdata[,i]/bankdata[,4]
}
names(bankdata)[(5:7)+3] =  paste0(names(bankdata)[5:7], 'toAssest')
```

Output:

```
bankdata
  bankname bankid year   totass   cash   bond loans cashtoAssest bondtoAssest loanstoAssest
1   Bank A      1 1881   244789   7250  20218 29513   0.02961734  0.082593581    0.12056506
2   Bank B      2 1881   195755  10243 185151  2800   0.05232561  0.945830247    0.01430359
3   Bank C      3 1881   107736  13357 177612     0   0.12397899  1.648585431    0.00000000
4   Bank D      4 1881   170600  35000  20000  5000   0.20515826  0.117233294    0.02930832
5   Bank E      5 1881 32000000 351266 314012     0   0.01097706  0.009812875    0.00000000
```