# Conditionally mutate columns based on column class

Tags: r, pipe, dplyr

My question is based on a previous topic posted here: [Mutating multiple columns in a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26219501/mutating-multiple-columns-in-a-data-frame/26219992)

Suppose I have a tibble as follows:

```
id   char_var_1   char_var_2   num_var_1   num_var_2  ... x_var_n
1       ...           ...         ...         ...           ...
2       ...           ...         ...         ...           ...
3       ...           ...         ...         ...           ...
```

where `id` is the key and `char_var_x` is a character variable and `num_var_x` is a numerical variable. I have 346 columns in total and I want to write a function that scales all the numerical variables except the `id` column. I'm looking for an elegant way to **mutate** these columns using pipes and dplyr functions.

Obviously the following works for all numeric variables:

```
pre_process_data <- function(dt)
{
  # scale numeric variables
  dt %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, scale)
}
```

But I'm looking for a way to exclude `id` column from scaling and retain the original values and at the same time scale all other numerical variables. Is there an elegant way to do this?

Comment: `dt %>% select(-id)` doesn't do it for you?

Comment: `dt %>% mutate(id = as.character(id)) %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, scale) %>% mutate(id = as.numeric(id))` ?

Comment: @JakeKaupp Please submit as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try below, answer is similar to [*select_if*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39592879) post:

```
library(dplyr)

# Using @Psidom's example data: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48408027

df %>%
  mutate_if(function(col) is.numeric(col) &
              !all(col == .$id), scale)
#   id a  b
# 1  1 a -1
# 2  2 b  0
# 3  3 c  1
```

Comment: I think this doesn't work in a situation where there is another column for which a number of rows share the same value with the `id` column.

`all(col != .$id)` will evaluate to `FALSE` in this case. I think it should be:

 `df %>%
  mutate_if(function(col) is.numeric(col) &
              !all(col == .$id), scale)`

Answer (score 2):

Not a canonical way to do this, but with a little bit hack, you can do this with `mutate_at` by making the integer indices of columns to mutate using `which` with manually constructed column selecting conditions:

```
df = data.frame(id = 1:3, a = letters[1:3], b = 2:4)
df %>% 
    mutate_at(vars(which(sapply(., is.numeric) & names(.) != 'id')), scale)

#  id a  b
#1  1 a -1
#2  2 b  0
#3  3 c  1
```

Answer (score 1):

How about the "make the column your interested a character, then change it back approach?"

```
  dt %>%
    mutate(id = as.character(id)) %>% 
    mutate_if(is.numeric, scale) %>% 
    mutate(id = as.numeric(id))
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use dplyr's [across](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html)

```
df %>% mutate(across(c(where(is.numeric),-id),scale))
```